# Prevent pandas to convert null objects as NaT

Tags: pandas

I create pandas series

```
pd.Series(["", pd.NaT, np.NaN], index=["a", "b", "c"])
```

returns

```
a   NaT
b   NaT
c   NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

but

```
print pd.Series(["?", pd.NaT, np.NaN], index=["a", "b", "c"])
```

returns

```
a      ?
b    NaT
c    NaN
dtype: object
```

How to make pandas not to automatically convert "null" objects to timedelta (except direct setting of `dtype`)?

Comment: so you cannot use `dtype` ? `(pd.Series(["", pd.NaT, np.NaN], index=["a", "b", "c"], dtype=object))` ?

Comment: @jezrael, i use it with ``for idx, row in df.iterrows()`` and then works with ``row`` :(

Comment: I dont understand - do you create dataframe form csv, dict, lists, array? and there is problem with automatically converting? Can you explain more? Why is impossible use parameter `dtype` ?

Comment: The ad-hoc is replace all ``""`` values in the column ``"a"`` with ``"?"``

Comment: why would you not want this behaviour?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems you need mixed columns with different types and I think the best is avoid it, because problematic use pandas function with it.

Comment: @EdChum, I process dataframe with MultiIndex columns with ``df.itterows()``. In some case it reads ``["", pd.NaT]`` is some level and returns row (Series) with ``timedelta`` as dtype. So replace ``""`` with something like ``"?"`` is only way for me.